# C function calculation issue where i either get an error or wont perform the calculation in my function

Tags: c, function

guys I am currently having a problem with my code. My code is for converting delta to star conversion, star to delta and quit. However this isnt important just a bit of background.
So for the code the calculations all have to be done in one function, and for some reason when I ask the user to enter a value for R1,R2 and R3 and then try to pass that through my function the calculation isnt performed, with the values the user inputted.
What I have commented out is not important as these bits work fine

Below is the part of the code i need help with

```
float conversions (float RA, float R1, float R2, float R3)
{
    //Star to Delta conversion

    RA = ((R1*R2+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3);
    
}


int main(void){
    float RA,R1,R2,R3;
    
    //printf("Please enter an S to convert Star to Delta, a D to convert Delta to Star, and Q to quit ");
    //char x = UserInput();
    //printf ("You selected %c\n", x);
    
    
    printf("Please enter a value for R1 R2 and R3 seperated by a space: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &R1, &R2, &R3);
    
    printf("%f %f %f", R1, R2, R3);  // test to ensure values were being passed to variables

    conversions(R1,R2,R3,RA);
    printf("%f", RA);
}
```

Comment: C is call-by-value, so the call `conversions(R1,R2,R3,RA)` will copy all of its arguments

Comment: Is it intended that in `conversions(R1,R2,R3,RA)` `RA` comes last but in `float conversions (float RA, float R1, float R2, float R3)` is comes first?

Comment: if the value in RA is to be returned then either the last statement in the function needs to be `return RA;` or the passed in parameter RA needs to be the address of the RA variable in `main()` and the rest of the `calculations()` function adjusted to match.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
float conversions (float R1, float R2, float R3)
{
    //Star to Delta conversion
    return (R1*R2+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
RA = conversions(R1,R2,R3);
```

or maybe this:

```
void conversions (float R1, float R2, float R3, float *RA)
{
    //Star to Delta conversion
    *RA = ((R1*R2+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3);    
}
```

and call it like this:

```
conversions(R1,R2,R3, &RA);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you

```
float conversions (float R1,float R2, float R3)
{
  //Star to Delta conversion
  return (R1*R2+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3;
}


int main(void){
float RA,R1,R2,R3;

//printf("Please enter an S to convert Star to Delta, a D to convert Delta to Star, and Q to quit ");
//char x = UserInput();
//printf ("You selected %c\n", x);


printf("Please enter a value for R1 R2 and R3 seperated by a space: ");
scanf("%f %f %f", &R1, &R2, &R3);

printf("%f %f %f", R1, R2, R3);  // test to ensure values were being passed to variables

printf("\n%f",conversions(R1,R2,R3));
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help was really stuck with this as am new to programming, again thanks a bunch

Comment: So, based on the help from MED LDN how would i adapt this so i can have multiple calculations happen inside of the conversion function?

Comment: @Dean if you tell us what exactly _"multiple calculations happening inside of the conversion function"_ is supposed to mean, then we can help. Probably you should ask another question.